# FluentMigrator generate SQL Output from In-Process Migration runner

Tags: c#, database-migration, fluent-migrator

Is there a way to generate SQL file output using the [In-Process Migration Runner](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/migration-runners.html?tabs=vs-pkg-manager-console) similarly to what can be achieved using [-output command argument](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/runners/dotnet-fm.html#-o--outputfilename) from the `dotnet-fm` tool.

I couldn't find any property, field or method in the `IMigrationRunner`, `IMigrationRunnerBuilder` or in the `IMigrationProcessorOptions` that would set configure the output.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://fluentmigrator.github.io/api/v3.x/FluentMigrator.Runner.Logging.FluentMigratorConsoleLoggerProvider.html
This page explains how to use a logging provider in fluent migrator.

https://fluentmigrator.github.io/api/v3.x/FluentMigrator.Runner.Logging.LogFileFluentMigratorLoggerOptions.html 
Here you can go over the different options, such as writing the logs to SQL database or to a file, or just showing the SQL in the console (if you use a consoleloggingprovider).

Here is how to do it:

```
services
    .AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, LogFileFluentMigratorLoggerProvider>()
    .Configure<LogFileFluentMigratorLoggerOptions>(
        opt =>
        {
            opt.OutputFileName = options.OutputFileName;
            opt.OutputGoBetweenStatements = targetIsSqlServer;
            opt.ShowSql = true;
        });
```

You could also write an extension method and a decorator to add custom logging providers, in case you want to log it somewhere else than the console. but I believe fluentMigrator already supports this out of the box.

Comment: The question is not about `EF`. Follow the links to Fluentmigrator

Comment: Oh, overlooked that, my bad. but even then, both EF and FluentMigrator provide ways to hook up logging providers. i will edit my answer

Comment: That is actually a smart idea, the hard part would be to filter each log message for the actual sql statement

Comment: You could look into the logging provider, and write your own implementation of it, where you filter on these sql statements. this will be pretty hard i think, but you could look into the documentation

Comment: If you look at the FluentMigratorLogger, you could easily write your own implementation, and just return out of the statements you don't need, except for writesql(). there you could do whatever you want. then register it in your IOC container. i'm not sure if setting the writeSQL bool to true only log's your sql statements.

Comment: sorry for the late answer, I am looking into it

Comment: Please see: https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator/issues/1078#issuecomment-539736631